# Writing a very simple lexical analyser in C++

Tags: c++, regex, token, lexical-analysis

NOTE : I'm using C++14 flag to compile... I am trying to create a very simple lexer in C++. I am using regular expressions to identify different tokens . My program is able to identify the tokens and display them. BUT THE out is of the form

```
int 
main
hello 
2
*
3
+
return
```

I want the output to be in the form

```
int IDENTIFIER
hello IDENTIFIER
* OPERATOR 
3 NUMBER 
so on...........
```

I am not able to achieve the above output.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = " hello how are 2 * 3 you? 123 4567867*98";

    // define list of token patterns
    map<string, string> v
    {
        {"[0-9]+" ,  "NUMBERS"} ,
        {"[a-z]+" ,  "IDENTIFIERS"},
        {"[\\*|\\+",   "OPERATORS"}
    };

    // build the final regex
    string reg = "";
    for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        reg = reg + it->first + "|";

    // remove extra trailing "|" from above instance of reg..
    reg.pop_back();
    cout << reg << endl;

    regex re(reg);
    auto words_begin = sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re);
    auto words_end = sregex_iterator();

    for(sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; i++)
    {
        smatch match = *i;
        string match_str = match.str();
        cout << match_str << "\t" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

what is the most optimal way of doing it and also maintain the order of tokens as they appear in the source program?

Comment: It seems that you are simply finding matches to your patterns but not associating them with their name, is that right? In that case, consider searching the whole text for each pattern individually and that'll solve your problem I think.

Comment: yes i am not able to associate them with there name. thats exactly correct. The method you suggest i ahvethought of it before but it suffers from two drawbacks..
1) simply searching the entire text (asumme it to be 1000 lines ) for different patterns is not a good idea.its costly operation

2) Even if i search the entire text the order of tokens will not be maintained..the output will contains ...all identifiers then all numbers and so on which is not required

Comment: Use a well know lexer (like `lex` or `flex`). You can build a lexer for what you want in about 5 minutes (and it will be much more efficient).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this with only one iteration over the parsed string. All you have to do is add parentheses around regex for each token type, then you'll be able to access the strings of these submatches. If you get a non-empty string for a submatch, that means it was matched. You know the index of the submatch and therefore the index in `v`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str = " hello how are 2 * 3 you? 123 4567867*98";

    // use std::vector instead, we need to have it in this order
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> v
    {
        {"[0-9]+" , "NUMBERS"} ,
        {"[a-z]+" , "IDENTIFIERS"},
        {"\\*|\\+", "OPERATORS"}
    };

    std::string reg;

    for(auto const& x : v)
        reg += "(" + x.first + ")|"; // parenthesize the submatches

    reg.pop_back();
    std::cout << reg << std::endl;

    std::regex re(reg, std::regex::extended); // std::regex::extended for longest match

    auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for(auto it = words_begin; it != words_end; ++it)
    {
        size_t index = 0;

        for( ; index < it->size(); ++index)
            if(!it->str(index + 1).empty()) // determine which submatch was matched
                break;

        std::cout << it->str() << "\t" << v[index].second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`std::regex re(reg, std::regex::extended);` is for matching for the longest string which is necessary for a lexical analyzer. Otherwise it might identify `while1213` as `while` and number `1213` and depends on the order you define for the regex.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick and dirty solution iterating on each pattern, and for each pattern trying to match the entire string, then iterating over matches and storing each match with its position in a map. The map implicitly sorts the matches by key (position) for you, so then you just need to iterate the map to get the matches in positional order, regardless of their pattern name.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string str = " hello how are 2 * 3 you? 123 4567867*98";

    // define list of patterns
    map<string,string> patterns {
        { "[0-9]+" ,   "NUMBERS" },
        { "[a-z]+" ,   "IDENTIFIERS" },
        { "\\*|\\+",  "OPERATORS" }
    };

    // storage for results
    map< size_t, pair<string,string> > matches;

    for ( auto pat = patterns.begin(); pat != patterns.end(); ++pat )
    {
        regex r(pat->first);
        auto words_begin = sregex_iterator( str.begin(), str.end(), r );
        auto words_end   = sregex_iterator();

        for ( auto it = words_begin; it != words_end; ++it )
            matches[ it->position() ] = make_pair( it->str(), pat->second );
    }

    for ( auto match = matches.begin(); match != matches.end(); ++match )
        cout<< match->second.first << " " << match->second.second << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
hello IDENTIFIERS
how IDENTIFIERS
are IDENTIFIERS
2 NUMBERS
* OPERATORS
3 NUMBERS
you IDENTIFIERS
123 NUMBERS
4567867 NUMBERS
* OPERATORS
98 NUMBERS
```

Comment: this does the trick but what actually i want to learn is what is the most effecient way of doing it cuz here also we need to iterate the whole text for every pattern. hope you understand .i want it for learning purpose

Comment: @erip I found other solution. You might be interested.

Comment: This is what i was looking for can you please explain it in a little more detail.That will help me very much.

Comment: Comment to my answer, what particularly do you need to know?

Comment: It is a nice experiment to check which of the two answers has the best performance.